# Setting Location on nginx for kibana security is not working

Tags: nginx, kibana-4

Hi Guys I want to add kibana security using nginx. and I have problem when setting the location configuration. Can I add location setting like this?

```
location ^~ /#/dashboard{....}
```

I tried and its not works. What I want is when I run kibana on localhost:8080/#dashboard then its goes to the location and do some checking. Can I do that?? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Nginx supports per location {} authentication. The simplest form of this is HTTP basic authentication.

First create a password file on your server in a location Nginx can see.

htpasswd -c /etc/nginx/conf/htpasswd username

Then inform Ngnix to authenticate users for your kibana location.

```
location ^~ /#/dashboard {
    ....
    auth_basic "password please";
    auth_basic_user_file conf/htpasswd;
}
```

Remember to reload Nginx and it will ask for the username and password you created with htpasswd when the location is visited.

Comment: Hi Steve, I already tried to use location ^~ /#/dashboard {...} but when I run localhost:8080/#/dashboard, its not running to that location and it will show nginx welcome page. I think maybe '#' character is the reason why it can't run to the location. And I use auth_request to do some checking. Thanks

Comment: The /#/dashboard is a different issue. As a general rule, anything after and including the # in a web address is not sent to the server so your location /#/dashboard block never matches. Try location / { instead or ask another question on this issue and somebody will help you.